# Appending parameters to WordPress query string in backend

Tags: url-rewriting

I'm creating a plugin that is using the `add_menu_page` function to create a page for my plugin options. This means that the url for my plugins main options page is like this

`http://localhost:8888/my-website/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-wordpress-plugin`

Now, in my plugin options page there is a standard form with a drop down menu that lets people choose what data they want to display.

```
<form>
  <select name="data-to-get">
   <option value="1">Foo</option>
   <option value="2">Bar</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="get-data">
</form>
```

Currently, when you select an option and click the button you are taken to this url:

`http://localhost:8888/my-website/wp-admin/admin.php?data-to-get=1`

This ends up loading a new page which is just blank. What I want to happen is this:

`http://localhost:8888/my-website/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-wordpress-plugin&data-to-get=1`

I know that WordPress has a built in function `add_query_arg` so I need to do something like this:

```
add_query_arg( 'data-to-get', '1', 'http://localhost:8888/LFB/wp-admin/admin.php?page=lfb-player-stats' );
```

However, where I'm stuck is that I don't know how to hook this in. It needs to be inserted after the select value has been chosen and when the get request from the form is sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a hidden input field to your form with name `page` and value `my-wordpress-plugin`, When the form is submitted it will be passed along with your other form data.

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="my-wordpress-plugin">
```